# Why isn't an a tag styled inside a div?

Tags: html, css, href

Why is the word "exemple" black here

```
<div style="color: red"><a href="http://exemple.com">Exemple</a></div>
```

while it becomes red here

```
<div style="color: red"><p>Exemple</p></div>
```

and even here

```
<div style="color: red"><a>Exemple</a></div>
```

Maybe there is a problem with 'href' attribute ?

PS : I know, that I can directly style an `<a>` tag, but I think my question is still interesting.

Comment: `a` does not inherit it's color from it' parent. It is an exception. You HAVE to style it directly, or set it explicitly to inherit. http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/inherit-css-property-value/

Comment: `a {color: red;}` you have to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser provides a default stylesheet.

In that stylesheet, the default value for the `color` property on an `a` element is a shade of blue, not `inherit`. You haven't done anything to override the value of the `color` property for the `a` element.

The default value for the property on the `p` element **is** `inherit`, so it pulls in the colour from its parent element.

Comment: So, I can consider a tag as as an exeption? Also, text-align works.

Comment: Many elements have properties with default values other than `inherit`. `text-align` doesn't even apply to inline elements, it affects the alignment of inline boxes within the block box to which it is applied.

Comment: *elements* aren't inherited at all, and border is a property not a selector. CSS properties may be inherited. By default, some are and some are not. The defaults are usually sensible ones. Links need to be distinguishable from surrounding text, and using an underline and colour is the traditional way to do that. If border was inherited by default, then you'd end up with [this sort of ugly mess](http://jsfiddle.net/g4m7X/) whenever you tried to use it.

Answer (score -1):

`a` does not inherit it's color from its parent. You have to style it directly, either through `a {color:red;}` or `<a style="color: red">`

Comment: Oh yes it does. And don't ever style things that way. (Unless you have a very, very good reason)

Comment: That's why I gave him the proper way first. And, a doesn't inherit its color from its parent unless you tell it to. Its color is blue by default.